# How can I check if a file contains a certain number that the user has input? (java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hi I'm trying to write a program that will check a designated file for a number that a user has input, however if the number is not present in the file I want the program to loop back to the beginning, how could I do this?

Here is the mess I've made so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Classtest2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //    //1. class
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(Classtest2.class.getResourceAsStream("trombones.txt"));
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What number would you like to check for?");
    String number = myScanner.nextLine() ;
    String keyWord = number, word;
    int lineNum = 0;

    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        word = sc.next();

        if(word.equals(myScanner.nextLine().trim())) {
            System.out.println("The number "+number+ " is there");

            break;
        } else {
            // not found
        }
    } // main
} // class
```

Comment: Add another `while` loop around the question/search structure and only exit it when it found something.

Comment: `if(word.equals(myScanner.nextLine().trim()))` is there a reason for asking the user for more input on every word of the given file?

Comment: I've been trying this for so long that I couldn't even tell you why i've done some of the things I have... Any example would help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need to do is take input from user and then check is it exist in file .you shouldn't use `myScanner.nextLine().trim()` inside while loop because then it waits to get user input every loop time .ones you get a number from user ,you should check it in the file .what you did is get user input and then again wait for user to input value again and again

fixed code

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Classtest2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        //    //1. class
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(Classtest2.class.getResourceAsStream("trombones.txt"));
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What number would you like to check for?");
        String number = myScanner.nextLine() ;
        int lineNum = 0;

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
            word = sc.next();

            if(word.equals(number.trim())) { //here was the problem
                System.out.println("The number "+number+ " is there");

                return;
            } else {

            }
        } 
        System.out.println("not found");  // not found
    }
```

the best approach

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Classtest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What number would you like to check for?");
        String number = myScanner.nextLine();
        if(isFound(number)){
            System.out.println("The number "+number+ " is there");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The number "+number+ " doesn't exist");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isFound(String number) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(Classtest2.class.getResourceAsStream("trombones.txt"));
        String word="";
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            word = sc.next();

            if (word.equals(number.trim())) { 
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However I added to the else statement to tell the user that the number is not present in the file, but as it's reading every line it says it is not present multiple times (the number of lines in the file) - is there a way around this?

Comment: I just used break; and solved it, thanks a lot everyone for your help!

Comment: @Samolivercz no no!! you shouldn't !! if you put a break inside else .it will only look user input does exist in the first line .it doesn't care if user input number exist in the 2 line of the file.check my updated answer .use return instead break

Comment: ah I see, I realized that shortly after running the program again haha, thanks for the help

Comment: A "best approach" that does not close his resource? Mhh, ok.

Comment: @Tom i'm not going to develop op's entire programe.

Comment: @fastsnail You don't have to, but classifying something like this as "best" is just misleading. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, hope is useful for you:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Classtest2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File f = new File("trombones.txt");
        f.createNewFile();
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean numExiste = menu(new Scanner(f), myScanner);
        while (!(numExiste)){
            numExiste = menu(new Scanner(f), myScanner);
        }
        myScanner.close();

    }

    private static boolean menu(Scanner fileScanner, Scanner myScanner) throws FileNotFoundException{
        String word = "";
        System.out.println("What number would you like to check for?");
        String number = myScanner.nextLine().trim();

        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
            word = fileScanner.nextLine();
            if(word.trim().equals(number)){
                System.out.println("The number "+number+ " is there");
                return true;
            }else{
                //Not the number
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The number "+ number+ " is not in the file\n\n");
        return false;

    }
} // main } // class
```